# Can't connect to any gaming servers

Tags: league-of-legends, steam

I am using a desktop with a wired connection. I can use Skype, surf the web. I can login to Steam on the browser.

I can't connect to League of Legends (logging in gives me a "Can't connect to maestro server" error). I can't connect to Steam (which gives me a "Can't connect to servers. Check your connection." error). I have flushed my DNS, checked proxy settings, checked internet settings (IPv4 DNS config), renewed IP, even checked hosts file.

On the other hand I can somehow play Hearthstone. On a laptop with a wireless connection I can login to League and Steam.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using windows, check that your wired and wireless network are configured the same way, the wired one might be configured with a more restrictive set of rules.

Comment: check your firewall

Comment: @luisluix Firewall is off, so is AV.

Comment: Do you have total control of your network? Are you behind a school, work, college residence network, or anything along those lines?

Comment: @TZHX Yes. I have direct access to the router. I have also tried DMZ to no avail.

Comment: And your network settings ? Are they the same ? Is one a home network and the other a work network for example.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Same router, basically default settings, laptop via 5Gz WiFi 802.11g/n works but Desktop via LAN does not. I should add that I used to be able to connect on my desktop but I'm not sure why suddenly I could not 2 days ago without installing anything, changing network settings, downloading Windows updates or anything.

Comment: I'm talking within windows network settings.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Haven't changed anything from factory install Windows 7. Looking at the adapter settings everything seems default.

Comment: check your ethernet cable, it may be broken, and be connecting/reconnecting. try using your laptop with the cable only and see if it works.

Comment: @luisluix I can surf the web with the ethernet cable - I doubt it's that. Anyways I have tried using the cable with my laptop and it works. I have reconnected the cable, restarted the router.

Comment: Check to see if you desktop thinks your network is "public." This may explain why you can no longer connect to it on your LAN

Comment: @Yorik It recognizes as home network.

Comment: If the same cable works with your Laptop, the problem has to be on your desktop machine. Does it have a WiFi card so you could try connecting it via WiFi?

Comment: @scenia No it does not have a WiFi card. Yeah I agree it's something to do with my desktop .

Answer (score 2):

According to the League of Legends Forums ([here](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2648025)) you can try this:

### Some sort of Maestro Error

1. Restart your computer
2. Temporarily Disable/Make exceptions in your Anti-virus/Anti-spyware software
3. Temporarily Disable/Make exceptions in your Firewall
4. Disable process protection software.
5. Make sure you're running software in Administrative Mode/With admin privileges
6. In Windows Vista/Windows 7, double check your Account Controls
7. Reset your Internet Explorer Settings and make sure you have not disabled scripting options

One person solved it by going to

> C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\projects\lol_air_client\releases\0.0.0.237\deploy

and setting LolClient.exe to run as admin.

One person updated Windows by running Windows Update and the problem was solved.

It's quite a common error and many people have odd ways of solving it. But since LoL and Steam don't connect I assume it's strictly connection or permissions.

**EDIT**:
[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FoXZ0kl2RM) a video that explains how to fix the problem. (He explains the Maestro Error at 2 min 24 sec. It has to do with Anti-Virus ;) )

I've had this happen to me and it was the Anti-Virus I was running (Kaspersky btw). I tried white-listing it on the firewall, Virus list EVERYTHING and it still didn't work. The only way I managed it to work was to play with the Anti-Virus turned off. (But this was my personal case).

**END EDIT**

If you can solve it for LoL you will most likely solve it for Steam.

I wish you good luck! and I hope that I gave you some good things to try and fix the problem since we never know for sure what the solution is.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either :/ Tried that, reinstalled League, and tried it again but nope

Comment: @M.Shaw please check my answer again. I've edited and added some more stuff. please take a look at it and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can suggest is calling your internet provider. Best thing you can do is get an I.T. guy to come check it out. Only thing I think that's possible to check on your router settings would be ports, but other than that, and based on the comments, I think this is on their part.

Comment: If it were the ports I highly doubt that my laptop would be able to access LoL/Steam and that my flatmate has no issues on  his LAN connection through the same router-modem-ISP.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a server browser problem. I just had a similar issue a few days ago which was solved by deleting 2 steam files:

> Serverbrowser Problems
>
> If you only have a problem with servers listing or staying listed or
>   in history (but can play otherwise (client problem), you should be
>   able to solve the problem by **closing Steam, deleting masterservers.vdf
>   and serverbrowser.vdf in the Config directory, and re-launching Steam**.

[Source](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6253-IOAB-2296&l=english)

I could not see any servers when I right-clicked on the steam tray icon and selected "servers." I also could not get a server list from within a particular game (*Killing Floor*). It seemed to hang on "getting master server list" and never got a list.

Comment: I've reinstalled Steam twice and tried deleting every file except `Steam.exe` itself to no avail.

Answer (score -3):

That thing happend to me before and there is MANY reasons why you can't connect to maestro server but you have to check 1 thing right now it might be sound but most people even programmers Don't check it first.
(Register The one and the only)
No matter how many times you will delete a file or reinstall it
as long the Register files are passed in the windows folder.
IT'S GAME OVER already if you have no idea how to check it.
The way to do it's kinda hard AND if you do 1 mistake and you happend to delete wrong files that happend your windows to use them
(you might wana re-install windows for GOOD because your pc wont be the same it used to be)
kind of advice? DON'T TOUCH REGISTER FILES if you dont know where to look
and i'll be honest even i have no IDEA where is the file you have to locate because of Riot.
Every time they update the game new stuff they put in register and i belive that 1 old files from register might stuck with others.
What you have to do? 
1) Because riot might NOT help you instally and they will ask you many things and even if you do them they will ask you to repeat them again and again.
2) instead trying to find any clue about where to find the files... instead go and download CCleaner and run a clean up register all files gona be removed *EXPECT windows files* that are NOT connected with the file location. Don't worry you can keep a back up so nothing bad will happend
!!! BUT first run it before you uninstall the game to see IF by chance it will work and if that won't work Then unistall it !!!

3) If nothing work Grab a hammer, scream "IT'S HAMMER TIME" and start hammering your pc Hard. after that try to start your pc, if your pc is still working... Repeat 3rd stage again XD (sorry mate could not resist)